# Image stored on physical drive to URL on website

Tags: c#, image, url

I want to store images on a separate physical drive eg. D:\images\{UserID}\picture1.jpg (note UserID is a folder with a Guid value) and translate that to a URL on my website for example https://www.website.com/images/picture1.jpg or maybe [https://www.website.com/images/{UserID}/picture1.jpg](https://www.website.com/images/%7BUserID%7D/picture1.jpg). If I click on an image, it shows the larger image. The source project may be stored on my C:\Project drive. I also want to create a grid layout of images like on YouTube. I’ve looked all over the internet for a solution but have not found what I needed. Anybody got any recommendations for this problem?

I know from my research that I’ve found many examples on the internet that show you can put an images folder in your project or have an images folder in your wwwroot folder but that’s not what I want. Lastly will there be any problems security wise with using a userID as a folder name?

Here are some code examples that I found on the internet:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/812675/how-to-show-an-image-in-image-control-retrived-pat

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133616/reading-and-displaying-an-image-from-a-folder

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Side q: would you mind explaining why you've added "I have not tried anything yet" to the post and what effect you wanted it to have? (Especially after reading help articles like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users linked from [help])

Comment: So you would like to store images on a local drive and display them on a website hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I think that is correct